# Duplicity: switch to "secondary backup chain"

Tags: duplicity

I ran `duplicity` when my backup drive wasn't connected, and it deleted lots of cached `sigtar` and `manifest` files:

```
Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
Deleting local /Users/justin/.cache/duplicity/a7190bc7f0d9f083cbc7e03931a8c95f/duplicity-full-signatures.20160608T054248Z.sigtar.gz (not authoritative at backend).
Deleting local /Users/justin/.cache/duplicity/a7190bc7f0d9f083cbc7e03931a8c95f/duplicity-full.20160608T054248Z.manifest (not authoritative at backend).
Deleting local /Users/justin/.cache/duplicity/a7190bc7f0d9f083cbc7e03931a8c95f/duplicity-inc.20160608T054248Z.to.20160610T041839Z.manifest (not authoritative at backend).
Deleting local /Users/justin/.cache/duplicity/a7190bc7f0d9f083cbc7e03931a8c95f/duplicity-inc.20160610T041839Z.to.20160616T043456Z.manifest (not authoritative at backend).
```

Now, when I run duplicity, it tries to do a full backup instead of finding my existing incremental backups.

Running `duplicity collection-status file:///Volumes/DuplicityBackup/` shows that my backup chain has become a "secondary backup chain", and there is an empty "primary backup chain":

```
$ duplicity collection-status file:///Volumes/DuplicityBackup/

Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
Last full backup date: Thu Jul 28 22:17:39 2016
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: LocalBackend
Archive dir: /Users/justin/.cache/duplicity/a7190bc7f0d9f083cbc7e03931a8c95f

Found 1 secondary backup chain.
Secondary chain 1 of 1:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Tue Jun  7 22:42:48 2016
Chain end time: Wed Jul 27 07:19:47 2016
Number of contained backup sets: 23
Total number of contained volumes: 2329
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
                Full         Tue Jun  7 22:42:48 2016              2219
         Incremental         Thu Jun  9 21:18:39 2016                20
         Incremental         Wed Jun 15 21:34:56 2016                 6
         Incremental         Fri Jun 17 07:29:49 2016                 1
...
-------------------------


Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Thu Jul 28 22:17:39 2016
Chain end time: Thu Jul 28 22:17:39 2016
Number of contained backup sets: 1
Total number of contained volumes: 0
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
-------------------------
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.
```

**How can I fix this?** (ie, delete the empty "primary backup chain" and use the "secondary backup chain")

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem a few weeks ago and what worked for me was to wipe duplicity's cache and manually remove all of the new primary chain files from the backend.